# Sticky Menu on oceanwp theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using oceanwp theme,
I want to have topbar that disappears when scrolling and the menu will jump to the topbar place (with opacity)  i was trying this code

```
#site-header {
  position: fixed;
  left: auto;

  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2000;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

and that not working,
the menu is stick in his place and there is a hole in the topbar place,
someone know how to fix it?

Comment: provide all related css, html markups

Answer (score 0):

Can you send to us link to your site, this gonna make everything more easy. If, this 'sticky' menu is creating with jquery or vanilla js then your css fixes doesn't change anything. Just check your js files for ".scroll(" and you should find this snippet.

//Sorry for my english skills :/

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};



function myFunction() {

    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 50) {
        document.getElementById("site-header").style.top='auto';
    } else{
        document.getElementById("site-header").style.top=0;

    }
}
```

I know it's not the best semantic solution, but its should work for your site. Add this to custom js, or another js file.

I checked on your site and its working :)

Comment: Ok, i see, you can make its to top=0 with javascript or jQuery, like here https://codepen.io/jdlaplan/pen/lboeD 

Try make it yourself because its really easy and you just must to catch #site-header id element and when window.scroll just give him style.top=0 or add custom class .headerOnScroll{ top: 0; ) Good luck :) If you gonna have any problems with that, just comment here.

Comment: can you please check
https://some1two.com/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/assets/js/core/scrollEffect.js
to see if it exist already here
I'm not strong in JS
and if its exist what should i write in the CSS?

Comment: Now I see its problem with jQuery on your site "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".

Comment: You cant fix it in the js file when you have:

$('.menu').addClass('original').clone()...

you must take all this code in this:

(function($){
    //script
})(jQuery);

so in your situation 

(function($){
$('.menu').addClass('original').clone()...
})(jQuery);

Comment: This error shouldn't be in developed theme, did you change anything in site scripts?

Comment: Thanks..
can you tell me what should I write now in the CSS to call it ?

Comment: no, you just add it to any javascript file in your wordpress theme, or on your header.php file in that way:

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};



function myFunction() {

    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 50) {
        document.getElementById("site-header").style.top='auto';
    } else{
        document.getElementById("site-header").style.top=0;

    }
}
</script>

Comment: or if your theme support that option add this to custom JS.

Comment: One last problem. 
I don't know if its in the js code or I need to write some CSS,
when the site is loading the menu hides the topbar, only if scrolling up it fixed...what do you think?

Comment: Yep, try change this class:

 #site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2000;
    opacity: 0.9;

just give top: auto;

Comment: Do you have any idea why in Internet explorer the menu doesn't jump to top when scrolling, it stick in his place?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code to your custom CSS/js in the theme customizer section and vuala!

```css
#site-header {position: stuck; left: auto;
  width: 100% z-index: 2000;opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
#site-header {
    position:fixed !important;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}

#main {
  margin-top: 70px !important; /* 70px - width of the header. This can be changed from the theme customizer */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header to scroll with the page until a certain point, and then stick to the top, use `position: sticky`. If you want the header to always stay at the top of the viewport, regardless of scrolling, use `position: fixed`.

in your case, you should have chosen `sticky`. This is the correct code in your case:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #site-header {
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0px; /* Edit until it suits your header, mine was 32px */
    z-index: 2000;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
```